# Cluster nearby points into one polygon

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, spatial

I have a table with two columns id and shape where shape is column dimension of type geography and  each row represents a point on map and it's required to cluster nearby points into clusters of type polygon in SQL Server.

My approach is to create a buffer around each point with a reasonable distance

```
SELECT shape.STBuffer ( distance )  
FROM table
```

then merge all intersecting buffers into a single  polygon (cluster) with area of the intersection between buffers, and if a buffer has no intersection then get the buffer as its own cluster

I'm not sure how to implement this query I was thinking using `buffer.STIntersects(buffer)` and recursively  getting the intersection using `STIntersection`.

If anyone could help with this query or point me to a different approach to the problem that would be great!

Comment: Interesting! It seems like you want something akin to [UnionAggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/unionaggregate-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16) but using Intersection as the operator. It might be worth a dip into [CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregates?view=sql-server-ver16) to write that aggregate function.

Comment: Wouldn't intersecting circles lead to some strange venn shape in the end of the operation? Since only trivially close points would intersect with each other nicely. One usually wants to have a nice circle as cluster at the end IMHO

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit late, but your approach is definitely doable, and without loops/recursion.  The steps we want to take are:

1. Buffer each point

   Shape.STBuffer(10)
2. Do a union aggregate to turn all the buffers into a single

   multipolygon - GEOGRAPHY::UnionAggregate(BufferedShape)
3. Break the multipolygon into individual polygons per record

   CROSS JOIN Numbers; MultipologonOfBufferedShapes.STGeometryN(Numbers.N)
4. Join those polygons back to the original shapes

Here's a working example of that with 30 random points across the globe:

```
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE (
  N INT
)
DECLARE @i INT = 0
WHILE @i <= 100
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @Numbers VALUES (@i)
  SET @i = @i + 1
END

DECLARE @SpatialTable TABLE (
  ID INT,
  Shape GEOGRAPHY
)

INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (1,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-57, -154, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (2,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-52, 140, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (3,GEOGRAPHY::Point(27, 101, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (4,GEOGRAPHY::Point(69, 98, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (5,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-60, -168, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (6,GEOGRAPHY::Point(80, 39, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (7,GEOGRAPHY::Point(64, 140, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (8,GEOGRAPHY::Point(53, 34, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (9,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-51, 139, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (10,GEOGRAPHY::Point(10, 84, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (11,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-30, -160, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (12,GEOGRAPHY::Point(16, -38, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (13,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-78, 56, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (14,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-7, 28, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (15,GEOGRAPHY::Point(31, -21, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (16,GEOGRAPHY::Point(80, -140, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (17,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-71, 83, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (18,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-68, 171, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (19,GEOGRAPHY::Point(60, 75, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (20,GEOGRAPHY::Point(6, 159, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (21,GEOGRAPHY::Point(39, -109, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (22,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-15, -11, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (23,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-71, -40, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (24,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-71, 48, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (25,GEOGRAPHY::Point(23, -131, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (26,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-42, 169, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (27,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-2, -26, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (28,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-85, -72, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (29,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-38, 5, 4326))
INSERT INTO @SpatialTable VALUES (30,GEOGRAPHY::Point(-72, -161, 4326))


SELECT
  S.ID AS ShapeID,
  S.Shape,
  N.N AS ClusterID,
  AllBuffers.STGeometryN(N.N) AS Cluster
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      GEOGRAPHY::UnionAggregate(Shape.STBuffer(1000000)) AS AllBuffers
    FROM 
      @SpatialTable
  ) B
CROSS JOIN
  @Numbers N
INNER JOIN
  @SpatialTable S
ON
  S.Shape.STIntersects(AllBuffers.STGeometryN(N.N)) = 1
WHERE
  N.N BETWEEN 1 AND B.AllBuffers.STNumGeometries()
```

Comment: This solution ended up being the key for me to get SQL Server to perform an approximation of the DBSCAN algorithm which is available in PostGIS natively as [`ST_ClusterDBSCAN`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html).  It's possible to port this solution to native SQL (no procedure, no variables) and additionally perform partitioning by adding a `group by` call within the `B` subquery.